# Packaging a particular version of java with my code

Tags: java

I've built a standalone Java Maven app. I need a particular version of java for running my code e.g. 1.8.0.155. My target environment has an older version. E.g. 1.8.0.45.
For various reasons I'm unable to get the target system to update their version of java.
How do I just bundle a version of the jdk along with my jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is how ot create a self-contained application, [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html) is how you do it without any third part assistance. Another option is [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/), a third party wrapper.